# Pass a data to the Button href in the modal

Tags: php, jquery, html

I do have a table ,which contains the delete button to delete the particular user.
so when i click the delete button, a confirmation modal displays and when i click the delete button ,the particular user has to be deleted.

Button that trigger the **modal**

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;">
   <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;">
            <button onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url('Employee/viewEmployee/'.$id) ?> ' " type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-inverse waves-effect waves-light" style="float: none;margin: 5px;">
              <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </button>
            <button onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url('Employee/editEmployeeView/'.$id) ?> ' " type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" style="float: none;margin: 5px;">
              <span class="icofont icofont-ui-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#default-Modal" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-yourparameter="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="float: none;margin: 5px;">
              <span class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></span>
            </button>
         </div>
    </div>
 </td>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="default-Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <h5>Are you sure?</h5><br>
           <p>By proceeding ,the data will be permanently deleted.You will not  be able to recover once it is deleted</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect " data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light " onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url('Employee/deleteEmployee/'.$id) ?>' ">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Currently when i click the button,the modal is open by default. I didn't write any additional script other than the jquery library.

*What i want to do is to pass the id to the modal.*

I'm new to javascript and jquery. 
I tried some of the answers mentioned in the other questions, but irrespective of the code i use,it didn't work out;the modal is opened by the jquery library's method (i think).

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: What part have you got stuck at? You don't appear to have described that actual problem you've encountered.

Comment: I want to pass the id to the modal

Comment: currently when i load modal, it shows error message as 'undefined variable id'.

Comment: is the modal div in the same page than the button that activates it?

Comment: Both the button and the modal are in the same page.

Comment: then you should have access to the variable in the modal

Comment: How are you getting `$id` ?

Comment: now, i just placed the code after the button that activate the modal. now undefined error seem solved., but, When i click any button ,only the id of the first button get passed. I want to pass respective id's of the button.

Comment: $id=base64_encode($key->emp_id);

Answer (score 1):

I think that you POST the ID to process it with `PHP`.

Use the `onclick` function to replace the value in your onclick method:
 
Place this at the bottom of your code!

```
<script>
$(".tabledit-delete-button").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
       var myID = $(this).data('id');
       $("#default-Modal .btn-danger").attr("onclick","location.href='/Employee/deleteEmployee/'" + myID);
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you have your value inside the modal.
This prevents the need of multiple same modals.

Check out this JSfiddle I made for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/Jbotman/f4voxes8/1/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185487/discussion-on-answer-by-jelle-botman-pass-a-data-to-the-button-href-in-the-modal).